# Excel VBA that reacts to an OLE Checkbox object being clicked also locks the keyboard - but why?

Tags: vba, excel, ole

I have a checkbox "Check_Group" in a worksheet "FA 2.0 Pricing Worksheet".  I have a subroutine defined in said worksheet that changes some values elsewhere when the user clicks on it:

```
Private Sub Check_Group_Click()

    Active = ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets("FA 2.0 Pricing Worksheet").Activate 'This activate has to happen here because there are some steps in a different routine where this checkbox has to be clicked programmatically
    If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Check_Group").Object.Value = True Then
        Sheets("FA 2.0 Risk Checklist").Range("UI_GROUP_RISK").Value = "No"
    Else
        Sheets("FA 2.0 Risk Checklist").Range("UI_GROUP_RISK").Value = "Yes"
    End If
    Sheets(Active).Select

End Sub
```

This works like a charm, except I've noticed a particularly annoying side-effect - the keyboard seems to lock after you click on it!

I can click into cells and navigate around the sheet with no problem, but when I try to type into (an unprotected) cell it doesn't react to my key presses at all.

I have confirmed with the debugger that *EnableEvents* and *ScreenUpdating* are both on.

I can skirt around the issue by clicking to another tab and back - typing works as normal then... in the exact same cells where it failed to type before! I'd still like to find a solution rather than just this cheap workaround though.

This is in Excel 2016.

Why does my subroutine lock the keyboard?

Comment: What's `Sheets(Active).Select` supposed to be doing? And why pull `ActiveSheet` by name, from the `Sheets` collection anyway?

Comment: That comment in the code is a bit mysterious.

Comment: The checkbox value sometimes has to be set automatically based on what data is pulled in from the database.  That data pull is triggered by a user action and can be on a number of different tabs.  When the data-pull is done, I wanted the screen to be on whatever tab they were on when they triggered the action - it's more intuitive for the user that way.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to activate the sheet for your code to execute.
And, when you're in a sheet code module you can refer to the sheet using `Me`

```
Private Sub Check_Group_Click()
    Me.Range("UI_GROUP_RISK").Value = IIf(Me.Check_Group.Value, "No", "Yes") 
End Sub
```